What does mathematics look like in a paraconsistent logic?
For an introduction to paraconsistent logic, see here; however, this question is aimed at people adept in the subject.
The Question:

What does mathematics look like in a paraconsistent logic?

Clarification:
Which paraconsistent logic? There is many.
Well, any of them. Pick your favourite. You may stick to three-valued logics if you wish, as long as you state which.
What sort of answer(s) am I looking for?
Some mathematical theorems that hold only in a paraconsistent logic, with a brief description of why they hold. You needn't go into detail. This is intended to have introductory level answers. References would help enormously.
What do I know so far?
I have the ebook of Mortenson's, "Inconsistent Mathematics", but I don't have time to read it. It is beyond me. Perhaps answers here will reignite my enthusiasm enough to propell me through that difficult text . . .
Further Motivation:
Nonclassical logics have fascinated me for a long time but I'm often afraid they're pseudo-science. If I have a reliable taste of what is and what isn't valid mathematically in them, I would be much more confident of their legitimacy. So here I am focusing on paraconsistency.

See Inconsistent Mathematics

And see Graham Priest, Inconsistent Models of Arithmetic: Finite Models (1997) for the description of some models.
